# How to set taxonomy hierarchical level to 2?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy and registered it. I want the taxonomy maximum level should me 2. i.e. Parent => child => sub-child. How to set level??

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a level when you create the taxonomy.

The only way to enforce a level is by watching the term creation: Filter `create_term`; that's the earliest filter that allows us to change parent term ID. For no obvious reasons the filter `pre_insert_term` is lacking that information … it would probably too easy.

Then change the parent term ID if the current on is already a second level ID.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_action( 'create_term', function( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {

    $term = get_term( $term_id );

    // Nothing to do.
    if ( empty( $term->parent ) )
        return;

    $parent = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );

    // This is a second level term, that's okay.
    if ( empty( $parent->parent ) )
        return;

    wp_update_term( $term_id, $taxonomy, [ 'parent' => $parent->term_id ] );
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: It creates the term then checks the parent. This is not a solution. I want to check if the term which is going to create has hierarchical level 2? If yes then give error msg else create the term.

Comment: @Deepakmodi The parent ID is not available in an earlier action. So you can at best delete the term here.

Comment: I don't know the solution yet.. But this method don't looks perfect as it allows to create the term. And then i have to delete that term. This is not effective way of doing. Better we have to not allow the term to create with pre_insert_term hook. But i don't know how to.